# Bound on number of function evalulations in FindMinimum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, options

I am minimizing a nonlinear constrained problem using `FindMinimum`. The problem involves about 200 variables and the function is a black-box which cannot be compiled/optimized (I have set the Method as Automatic).

During evaluations, I collect the value of the objective function at intermediate evaluations using `EvaluationMonitor` option. I have a `Monitor` statement enclosing the `FindMinimum` which plots the objectiveFunction against the number of function evaluations. This was the picture.

[image: objective_fn_against_num_of_fn_evals]

Is there an option to **(gracefully) terminate** the `FindMinimum` after `nMax` number of function evaluations, returning the best solution of those so far evaluated (like position 25 in the image)? ( `MaxIterations` does not achieve it, since it is a bound on the number of **steps taken** and not the function evaluations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[fun_, x0_, iters_] := 
 Reverse@First@Sort[
   Reap[Block[{n = 0, fval}, Catch[FindMinimum[fval = fun[x], {x, x0}, 
                                         EvaluationMonitor :> 
                                           (Sow[{fval, x}]; If[++n >= iters, Throw[0]])]]]][[2, 1]]]

f[Sin, 1, 8]
(*
 {-1.57247, -0.999999}
*)
```

.

```
Show[Plot[Sin@x, {x, -  2, 1}, AspectRatio -> 3/2], 
     Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Medium], Point@#, Line@#} &@ Table[f[Sin, 1, i], {i, 1, 10}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1. Did not know that the form `fval = fun[x]` will update `fval` on each evaluation of the objective function if `EvaluationMonitor` is specified. Such a very basic usage case should be in the Documentation!

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It has the clear advantage of saving one evaluation per step :)

Comment: Wait... What happens is not updating the `fval` but just assignment `fval = fun[x]` is made globally and then at each evaluation `fun[x]` is evaluated twice: once as objective function and once from `EvaluationMonitor`. This means that `fval` is not needed at all: you can put `fun[x]` in the monitor with the same effect. I was too fast.

Comment: You can see this with `n=0; f[_?NumberQ] := (n++; Sin[x]);
FindMinimum[fval = f[x], {x, 1}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print[{n, fval}]]` and also with `FindMinimum[fval = Sin[x], {x, 1}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print[OwnValues@fval]]`.

Comment: +1 for fval = fun[x]. It works

Comment: to make sure it performs utmost `iters` no of evals, need to replace >= with = (can't edit it - min num of chars required for edits to be accepted)