# Why is EvaluationMonitor not always run when the objective function is called?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, monitoring

A simple demonstration:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := (Print["f[x]"]; x^4 - 3 x^2 - x)
NMinimize[f[x], x, EvaluationMonitor :> Print["EvaluationMonitor"], MaxIterations -> 1]
```

I would except that the output is a repetition of

```
f[x]
EvaluationMonitor
f[x]
EvaluationMonitor
...
```

but if I look at the later stages of the output, this shows that the `EvaluationMonitor` is not always called when `f[x]` is called, and the output looks more like this:

```
f[x]
f[x]
f[x]
f[x]
f[x]
...
EvaluationMonitor
f[x]
f[x]
...
```

I get the same behavior for other functions such as `FindMinimum`. The example function is not linear, so I guess this is not the same issue as in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81096/why-does-evaluationmonitor-in-findmaximum-only-work-for-some-regions)?

This mainly bothers my because sometimes I have much more complex (non-linear) functions, sometimes with external program calls, and I want to use [this method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35042/bound-on-number-of-function-evalulations-in-findminimum) to gracefully terminate the optimization after a number of iterations - and if `EvaluationMonitor` is not executed every time the function is called, this gets complicated...

**EDIT:**

Another demonstration, also showing the values of the variable `x` when `f[x]` is called (+ low settings for the various Precision options):

```
f[x_?NumericQ]:=(Print["f["<>ToString[x//FullForm]<>"]"];x^4-3 x^2-x)
NMinimize[f[x],x,EvaluationMonitor:>Print["EvaluationMonitor"],MaxIterations->1,AccuracyGoal->2,PrecisionGoal->2,WorkingPrecision->4]
```

If you look at the output, you can see that some (all?) of the calls of `f[x]` that happen without running the `EvaluationMonitor` were already run before with the identical `x`. For example:

```
...
f[1.3414060135376415805`4.]
EvaluationMonitor
f[1.3414060135376415805`4.]
f[1.4842631563947844377`4.]
f[1.6271202992519272948`4.]
f[1.1985488706804987234`3.907144839865827]
f[1.0556917278233558663`3.8121174553460224]
EvaluationMonitor
f[1.3414060135376415805`4.]
f[1.4842631563947844377`4.]
f[1.6271202992519272948`4.]
f[1.1985488706804987234`3.907144839865827]
f[1.0556917278233558663`3.8121174553460224]
EvaluationMonitor
f[1.354820073673017999`4.]
...
```

This seems relatively unnecessary to me, and for the cases where one call of `f[x]` takes a relatively long time, these calls increase the time to find an optimum dramatically. Sometimes I only need a rough estimate - but as you can see, adjusting the `Precision` options does not help with this issue.

Comment: curious observation. Have you tried putting the counter and `Throw` inside the function as a work around?

Comment: @george2079 I guess this would work, but it doesn't help with the "unnecessary" calls of the function - I added another example to the original post to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EvaluationMonitor` keeps track of the evaluations caused by `NMinimize` directly; the "extra" evaluations come from the post-processing done by the low-level optimization routines called by `NMinimize`.

In fact, you can prevent the extra evaluations of `f` by turning the post-processing off:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_?NumericQ] := (Print["f[x]"]; x^4 - 3 x^2 - x)

NMinimize[
 f[x], x,
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print[Style["eval", Blue]],
 MaxIterations -> 3, Method -> {"NelderMead", "PostProcess" -> False}
]
```

[image: nice alternating f and eval]

More in general, you can still let the `NMinimize` heuristics choose the method automatically, but turn off the post-processing, using `Method -> {Automatic, "PostProcess" -> False}`.

See the various options here: [Numerical Algorithms for Constrained Global Optimization - Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html#252245038)

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I was looking for... The PostProcess option is not explained in the main `NMinimize` description - I didn't know that sometimes there are details that are only explained in the tutorials!